# Auto close browser after opening application using web intent filter?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am running into an issue using an intent filter to launch my application. I have the following intent filter set on the splash screen of my application.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="myhost" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Now this works perfect for launching my application using myscheme://myhost. The issue is that this first opens a browser window and than instantly opens the application. Is there a way to still have this behavior of clicking a link in email or something like that and opening the app without also opening a browser first?

Comment: I have tried a few window close hacks but none seem to work on the Android browser...